# Next React child component uses old props when rendering which causes an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component who has an A component and a B component as children. When i'm on A, i get data by click a button, the parent component is re-rendering after fresh data has been set to parent's state, everything is okay. But when i switch to B, B keeps A's data and crashes as A and B data structures are different. How could i reset parent's state when route changes for B to not use A's data?

I tried to give child components key props but as i'm using React.cloneElement to render them, i didn't figure out how to actually do it correctly.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: null
  };

  getData = async () => {
    // asynchronously fetch data from api and set response as new data value
    this.setState({ data });
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        Home
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/a">A</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/b">B</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <button onClick={this.getData}>Get data</button>
        {Children.map(children, child =>
          React.cloneElement(child, { data: this.state.data })
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const BrowserRouter = createBrowserRouter({
  routeConfig: makeRouteConfig(
    <Route path="/" Component={App}>
      <Route path="a" Component={A} />
      <Route path="b" Component={B} />
    </Route>
  ),

  renderError: (
    { error }
  ) => <div>{error.status === 404 ? "Not found" : "Error"}</div>
});
```

Expected results would be to get A's data while on A, go to B and get B's data. But actually B's using A data to render and crashes.

Comment: Something looks off with your getData method, for a start it doesnt seem do what the name of it suggests, it sets data rather than gets data, but more importantly when you set the data, what is data? I don't see how data could be anything but undefined

Comment: Ok so i wanted the code to be clean enough to be understood but it seems it's not the case. getData is in fact an async method fetching data from a specific endpoint. Actually there is a global data variable higher in the file.